# Java - What is the simplest was to find if a position exists in an array of primitives?

Tags: java, arrays, primitive, primitive-types, indexoutofboundsexception

I have an array of characters, and, for the type of program I have, it will have to check indexes over the boundaries by design. I thought I'd got around this but evidently not. So is there a way to check if an index is out of bounds or not?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Get the `array.length` which gives how many elements exists in array. Available index will be one less than length of array.

Comment: @Tim No, you're not, just sometimes, we're to close to the trees to see the forest ;)  Don't forget, if you really want to show your appreciation, marking the question answered is the best way ;)

Comment: @MadProgrammer Thank you, +1 for a nice and helpful comment :-)

Answer (score 1):

I hope that I understood your question properly.
I wrote this code.
It is an array of characters,of length=5.
Now,if you want to print MyArray[8],it gives this error message:

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
```

Does this answer your question?
Did you want to use the following?:

```
if(index>MyArray.length) 
{
System.out.println("Index does not exist");

}
```

Here is the code:

```
 public class prac
        {
            public static void main(String args[])
            {
                char[] MyArray=new char[5];
                MyArray[0]='a';
                MyArray[1]='b';
                MyArray[2]='c';
                MyArray[3]='d';
                MyArray[4]='e';

                int index=7;
                System.out.println(MyArray[index]);
                System.out.println(MyArray);
                System.out.println(MyArray.length);
            }
        }
```